# Web Api Help Page - Show only some controllers but no others

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, xml-documentation

I've an application made in Web Api 2.1 (Visual Studio 2012 C#) and I made a Help page with XML Documentation.

I just want only expose some controllers, not all controllers of my Web Api, but at the same time I don't want to remove the comments from the methods, classes, properties, etc.

How can I select some elements and others not to show in my help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For every API controller that you would like to have excluded from the auto generated help pages you should add the following attribute to your controller:

```
 [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

P.S. You have to include the following using statement:

`System.Web.Http.Description`

Comment: This can also be applied to individual routes